# How to check if the model is valid in angular/typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular8

I have an `Angular 8` app.

My model looks as

```
export class UserModel
{
  name:string;
  email:string;
  age? :number; //optional (?)
}
```

a method in user.component.ts (or user.service.ts)

```
public addUser(user:userModel)
{
  if(model is valid)
  {
     //then call service & so on
  }

}
```

I do have HTML5 validators in my component template as

```
<div> 
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required /> 
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter your age"/>
</div>
```

> But I want to validate the model in the typescript as well? how can I
>   validate the model?

Comment: What is valid for you?

Comment: you can use reactive forms to validate forms

Comment: @TheUnreal Please check the model definition

Comment: Typescript type checks are only for compile time, not in run time. You can write an `isValid` function to the class yourself. That being said, the validity of model is ususally ensured in angular using ReactiveForms and Validators added to it.

Comment: @sabithpocker Agreed I thought the same. but want to write the valid function generic

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you have a form in your HTML, so you can use that to check the validity:

In your ts file :

```
@ViewChild(NgForm, {static: true}) form: NgForm;

public addUser(user:userModel)
{
  if(this.form.valid)
  {
    //then call service & so on
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check a model, if it is null or not by using if(model)

```
public addUser(user:userModel)
{
  if(user)
  {
     //execute the code
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with following code:

```
checkFormValidation(form, markTouchFlag: boolean = true) {

    if (form.invalid) {
        if (markTouchFlag) {
            this.markFormControlTouched(form.controls);
        }
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```